# Cordova/phonegap JS callbacks not invoked

Tags: javascript, plugins, callback, cordova

I have made a cordova project via the create script and have created a plugin.
However, for some reason, the JS-callbacks are not invoked whenever i send an pluginresult.

I have checked the callbackID. Its filled with a (seemingly) valid callback.
My plugin mapping is ok, the native code gets executed and there are no errors.

I have no clue as to why callbacks arent fired..

My javascript :

```
(function(cordova) {

    function Plugin() {}

        Plugin.prototype.FBAuthorize = function(config) {
            cordova.exec(null, null, "Plugin", "FBAuthorize", []);
        };

        Plugin.prototype.FBGetLoginStatus = function(cb, fail) {
            cordova.exec(function(){alert('test')}, function(){alert('test')}, "Plugin", "FBGetLoginStatus", []);
        }

        Plugin.prototype.FBPostToUserTimeline = function(textToShare, imageUrl, linkUrl) {
            cordova.exec(null, null, "Plugin", "FBPostToUserTimeline", [textToShare, imageUrl, linkUrl]);
        }

        if(!window.plugins) window.plugins = {};
        window.plugins.Plugin = new Plugin();

})(window.cordova || window.Cordova || window.PhoneGap);
```

my ios

```
(void) FBGetLoginStatus:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    CDVPluginResult* result = nil;
    NSString* javascript = nil;
    if([[FBSession activeSession] isOpen]) {
        result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"Logged in"];
        javascript = [result toSuccessCallbackString:command.callbackId];
    } else {
        result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"Not logged in"];
        javascript = [result toErrorCallbackString:command.callbackId];
    }
    [self writeJavascript:javascript];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not a expert in phonegap but this works for me you can try (iOS Code)

```
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

instead

```
[self writeJavascript:javascript];
```

i hope this help